# JavaFX: Expand a ComboBox programmatically

Tags: java, combobox, javafx

Does anyone know how to expand a `ComboBox` by code? I know that in `C#` we can do this by `comboBox1.DroppedDown = true;`, but how do I do this in `JavaFX`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After your stage is visible, simply use :

```
comboBox.show();
```

If you want to add a event, before the stage is visible, you may use :

```
primaryStage.setOnShown(event -> comboBox.show());
```